# How to get xPosition and yPossition when placing tag on DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

When setting up a signing session on Docusign, I'm able to upload the document, set signing session and add the tag for user to sign.  I know while using Docusign API, I can specify the X and Y position of the tag in the code.  However, does Docusign as a viewer via the API that I can view the document, place the tags to get the X and Y?  If not, what are people using?

Comment: If you manually tag up a document how you'd like it and get the x / y cords for each tag via the API (GET envelope), you can use those same cords to post a new envelope

Comment: Hi @Dat did my answer solve your issue?  If so can you accept please? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a specific workflow DocuSign offers for this, it's called **Embedded Sending** or the **Sender View** of an envelope.  Just like embedded signing (aka Recipient View) you can generate a custom URL that you use to view the envelope through a re-direct (or webview if using mobile).

Here's the corresponding REST API: [Create Sender View](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender/)

Sample Request:

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/sender

{
    "returnUrl": "https://www.docusign.com"
}
```

The **returnUrl** body parameter controls where the user is re-directed to once they are done editing and/or sending the envelope.